Collision detection side
    // ball starting position
    ball.x = app.screen.width/2;
    ball.y = 400;

    // ball.x = app.screen.width/2;
    // ball.y = 400;

    // moving platfrom basic settings (position and anchor)
    smallPlatform.x = app.screen.width/2;
    smallPlatform.y = 770;
    smallPlatform.anchor.set(0.5);
    

    blueBlock.x = app.screen.width/2;
    blueBlock.y = 200;
    blueBlock.width = 60;
    blueBlock.anchor.set(0.5);

    
    // adding objects to the stage
    app.stage.addChild(background);
    app.stage.addChild(ball);
    app.stage.addChild(smallPlatform);
    app.stage.addChild(blueBlock);

    // collision detection func for ball and other objects
    const rectCircleCollide = function (target, ball) {    

        const distX = Math.abs(ball.x - target.x);
        const distY = Math.abs(ball.y - target.y);
        if (distX > target.width / 2 + ball.radius ||
            distY > target.height / 2 + ball.radius    ) {
            return false;    }
        if (distX <= target.width / 2 || distY <= target.height / 2) {
            return true;    }
        const dx = distX - target.width / 2;
        const dy = distY - target.height / 2;
        return dx * dx + dy * dy <= ball.radius * ball.radius;
    
    };


        if (rectCircleCollide(blueBlock, ball)) {

            if (ball.y-ball.radius <= blueBlock.y+blueBlock.height/2 || ball.y+ball.radius >= blueBlock.y-blueBlock.height/2) {
                ball.ySpeed = -ball.ySpeed;
            }if (ball.x+ball.radius >= blueBlock.x-blueBlock.width/2 || ball.x-ball.radius <= blueBlock.x-blueBlock.width/2) {
                ball.xSpeed = -ball.xSpeed;
            }
        }
        
        // Collision detection for left, right walls and top.
        if (ball.x+ball.radius >= app.screen.width-25 || ball.x-ball.radius <= 25) { 
            ball.xSpeed = -ball.xSpeed;
        }else if (ball.y-ball.radius <= 25) {
            ball.ySpeed = -ball.ySpeed;
        }else if (ball.y+ball.radius > app.screen.height) {
            ticker.stop();
            // ball.ySpeed = -ball.ySpeed;
        }

Making Arkanoid game using pixijs lib. I need to find the side from which the ball collided with the blueBlock and change the ball's direction accordingly. in my code, for some reason, the direction changes incorrectly. Please help me find the sollutin.

Hi! can you create a [mre]?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
